# Is there an up to date heroku buildpack for R

Tags: r, heroku, buildpack

I am using the [virtualstaticvoid](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/tree/heroku-16) buildpack for heroku, but it is on the heroku-16 stack and only supports up to version 3.4.4 of R. I am after a buildpack that works on the latest stack (heroku-18) and supports at least version 3.6 of R, and has no outdated dependencies.  The [hmdc buildpack](https://github.com/hmdc/heroku-buildpack-r) appears to support heroku-18 and version 3.6.0 of R, but requires [packrat](https://github.com/hmdc/heroku-buildpack-r) which is soft deprecated in favour of renv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good news, [virtual_static_void](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r) has been updated so the `R buildpack` now uses version `4.0.0`, works on both `heroku-18` and `heroku-16` stacks, and it supports `renv`.

Comment: Note that the same buildpack you linked to now supports R 4.0.0 :)